# excel sheet validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I using laravel excel Maatwebsite.

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{

```
  Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
         '*.price' => 'numeric',
     ])->validate();
```

}

I need output

Excel Row No not array number

Row No 1.price must be a number.

Answer (score 1):

as I understand you need to validate uploaded excel rows.
the package `excel Maatwebsite` provided validation rules feature too.

in your import class you need to add  `WithValidation`, `WithHeadingRow` interface and `rules` mothod. in this way uploaded excel will be validated before insert into database:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow,SkipsOnFailure
{
    use Importable,SkipsFailures;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'email'    => $row['email'],
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => Rule::in(['patrick@maatwebsite.nl']),

             // Above is alias for as it always validates in batches
             '*.email' => Rule::in(['patrick@maatwebsite.nl']),
        ];
    }
}
```

and to gather errors:

```
 $import = new UsersImport();
$import->import('users.xlsx');
$failures= $import->failures() ;
foreach ($failures as $failure) {
     $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
     $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
     $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
     $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
}
```

now `$failures` contains all validation error in all rows

Comment: public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
            'price'     => $row['price'],
            'product'    => $row['product'],
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'price' => 'numeric',
             '*.price' => 'numeric',
        ];
    }
}

Comment: class ProductUpdate implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
            'price'     => $row['price'],
            'product'    => $row['product'],
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'price' => 'numeric',
             '*.price' => 'numeric',
        ];
    }
}
But not working no showing any in blade file

Comment: it's better to update your question to add more details not in comment

Comment: what do you mean `But not working no showing any in blade file `?

Comment: I think you mean how to get the errors. I updated my answer please check

Comment: I'm using this code but given only one error but i need all error on time like:-
Row No 1.price must be a number.
Row No 2.price must be a number.
Row No 3.price must be a number. --- Like this

Comment: I updated the answer. now it collects all errors

Comment: No working -- Only given single Error

Comment: did you implement `SkipsOnFailure` ? I forgot it.

Comment: return [
            'price' => Rule::in(['numeric']),
             '*.price' => Rule::in(['numeric']),
        ];
Please correct me

Comment: To validate the price column to be numeric you can use `price=>numeric`

Answer (score 0):

This example use interface **Validator** that take different arguments to initialize; [`(array $data, array $rules, array $messages, array $customAttributes)`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html) to validate rows and referenced from web sources, do not implement `ToModel` concern and is similar to the example showed in the question.

```php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
         Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
             '*.0' => 'required',
         ])->validate();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            User::create([
                'name' => $row[0],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Another scenario like defined a custom data or Excel file like the following, suppose you want to access specific cells, you can implement the `WithMappedCells` concern.

| index | user | date | subscription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | user | 2022-12-08 | true |
| 1 | user | 2022-12-08 | true |
| 2 | user | 2022-12-08 | false |
| 3 | user | 2022-12-08 | true |

```php
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;

class UsersImport implements WithMappedCells, ToModel 
{
    public function mapping(): array
    {
        return [
            'index'  => 'B1',
            'user' => 'B2',
            'date' => 'B3',
            'subscription' => 'B4',
        ];
    }
    
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'index' => $row['index'],
            'user' => $row['user'],
            'date' => $row['date'],
            'subscription' => $row['subscription']
        ]);
    }
}
```